# ts files not compiling when accessing from js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I write graphql API which including FHIR standards. I have decided to write API using typescript language but problem is FHIR schema, I am not getting a good example with typescript, So I got schema code and base setup for graphql API with FHIR standards from "https://github.com/Asymmetrik/graphql-fhir". I can able to work the only javascript but in my architect designed by typescript so I have to write business logic into typescript. 
  Here problem is ts file not compile it throws [image]

tsconfig.json:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "pretty": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es2016",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "allowJs": true,
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is a problem because the typescript files are not being converted to JS files. You need to use a converter like bable or webpack for the conversion or can use ts-node npm package for directly running ts file

Comment: Here problem "https://github.com/Asymmetrik/graphql-fhir" application start with help of nodemon they wrote separate code for nodemon

Comment: does npm run start works fine ?

Comment: i have to mention on script start: "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node src/query/graphql/scripts/nodemon"

Comment: without nodemon that github code not getting output

Comment: There is not file on location "src/query/graphql/scripts/nodemon" in you repo

Comment: i have file that location

Comment: send me the url from github

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202140/discussion-between-saranviji-and-ayush).